# Can't get image links to work in CSS carousel

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, carousel

I can't make some of the image links work in the CSS carousel.  I think the image(s) for the most part are blocking the image link, because when I move the image links away from the area of the underlying image, then the links actually work.  I tried z-index in my CSS code but that doesn't work.

```css
/* colorDissolve  */

.colorDissolve {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 95vh;
  height: 76vh;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.colorDissolve .item {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: colorDissolve 21s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: colorDissolve 21s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: colorDissolve 21s linear infinite;
  animation: colorDissolve 21s linear infinite;
}

.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

.colorDissolve .item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

.span1aa {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 25%;
  left: 27%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*image link not clicking*/

.span1aa a img {
  width: 66%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


/*bottom? image*/

.item img {
  z-index: 1;
}

.span1a {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 71%;
  left: 27%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.span1a a img {
  width: 62%;
}

.span1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 30%;
  left: 72%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.span1 a img {
  width: 95%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorDissolve {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.17%,
  20.84% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes colorDissolve {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.17%,
  20.84% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes colorDissolve {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.17%,
  20.84% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes colorDissolve {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.17%,
  20.84% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel colorDissolve">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="span1aa"><a href="https://joyfullinspirations.com/premium-starter-kit"> <img src="https://joyfullinspirations.files.wordpress.com/2024/01/starterkitoption-1_03-2.jpg" />
</a></span>
    <img src="https://joyfullinspirations.files.wordpress.com/2023/12/bigphoto-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="span1a"><a href="https://joyfullinspirations.com/classes-3/"> <img src="https://joyfullinspirations.files.wordpress.com/2024/01/coachservices_03.jpg" />
</a>
</span>
    <img src="https://joyfullinspirations.files.wordpress.com/2023/11/pexels-mohammad-danish-891059-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="span1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/JOYFullOilyFamily/">
<img src="https://joyfullinspirations.files.wordpress.com/2024/01/damnits-1_03-1.jpg" />
</a>
</span>
    <img src="https://joyfullinspirations.files.wordpress.com/2024/01/imagefbpost-1-4-4275899848-e1704339955680.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a codePen here:   https://codepen.io/emilysarah1/pen/GReoEzo

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have a layering issue. Your image, "pexels-mohammad-danish-891059-1.jpg," is overlapping the others, making it impossible to click on the images beneath.

Simply making the image transparent won't resolve the problem, as the image will remain in the same position even when invisible.

I suggest adding JavaScript to dynamically add/remove an  element during the transition. Alternatively, you can place a  element on each of your images and update its link during the animations.

(I apologize if my explanation is unclear or not helpful.)

Comment: Thanks.  Actually got a good idea from what you said.  Appreciate the help.